# SMTP with Python using SSL/TLS results in a timeout

Tags: python, email, ssl, smtp

I am attempting to send emails with Python, and I followed [this](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/) tutorial.

I tried two methods for connecting to the gmail server. The first method establishes a secure connection immediately. The second method opens an unsecure connection first, then encryption is applied after the connection is open.

Both methods result in a timeout.

For the first method, the timeout occurs after running `server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host, port, context=context)`.

For the second method, the timeout occurs after running `server.starttls(context=context)`.

This is for a work project, so I am using a company device. In the past, I needed to use a proxy to make certain API calls, and I instinctively tried this, but it was to no avail.

Is there an obvious reason as to why my program would timeout?

**Method 1**

```
import smtplib
import ssl

host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
port = 465
user = input()
password = input()
context = ssl.create_default_context()

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host, port, context=context) # The timeout occurs here.
server.login(user, password)
```

**Method 2**

```
import smtplib
import ssl

host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
port = 587
user = input()
password = input()
context = ssl.create_default_context()

server = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
server.starttls(context=context) # The timeout occurs here.
server.login(user, password)
```

Comment: first try on computer which doesn't need proxy - maybe this proxy doesn't redirect it correctly and then you have to reconfigure proxy server because you can't change it with code.

Comment: both version works for me but I don't use proxy.

Comment: Likely using TLS for SMTP is blocked by some corporate firewall. Many firewalls can do this in order to be able to analyze mail traffic. If you need this for a work project try to contact your IT administration so that they could add exceptions or recommend you an alternative way, like using your local SMTP server and not some external one.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @furas! It is reassuring that both methods work for you. I will give it a shot on my personal computer.

Comment: That makes sense, @SteffenUllrich. I appreciate your help. I think I will reach out to IT. Thanks!